# Fabric.js - how to create TextBox without line breaks?

Tags: javascript, textbox, fabricjs

I was searching a lot for properties like `maxLines`, `noWrap`, `splitByWhitespace`, etc. in [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) documentation, but they don't exist. Do you know a working solution to **disable text wrapping** inside `fabric.Textbox`?

my code:

```
const text = new window.fabric.Textbox('expected single line', {
  fontFamily: 'Nunito Sans',
  fontWeight: 400,
  fontSize: 15,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
});

const border = new window.fabric.Rect({
  rx: 10,
  ry: 10,
  fill: '#999999',
  height: text.height + 10,
  width: text.width + 100,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
});

const group = new window.fabric.Group([border, text], {
  originX: 'left',
  originY: 'top',
  hasRotatingPoint: false,
  height: 42,
  width: 200,
  top: 167,
  left: 50,
});
canvas.add(group);
```

actual result demo:

[image: multiline textbox]

as you can see there are line breaks on every whitespace, but I want to have a single-line text with spaces. interestingly, if I replace whitespaces with underscore `_`, I get one-line text.

demo:

[image: one-line textbox]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about disabling wrapping in the `Textbox`.
But to get a one-line text, you can

- either set the `Textbox` width
- or use `Text` instead of `Textview` (see this [codepen](https://codepen.io/mcernak/pen/ZEWamyY))

Answer (score 0):

originally found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41335051/1815624

this sorta does what you want by checking the add values of `fixedWidth` and `fixedHeight` then checking those compared to the new width after changing the text...

this is not really a solution but it may help you figure something out...

```js
// ADD YOUR CODE HERE
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var t1 = new fabric.Textbox('MyText', {
    width: 150,
    top: 5,
    left: 5,
    fontSize: 16,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fixedWidth: 150,
    fixedHeight: 20,
});

canvas.on('text:changed', function(opt) {

    
  var t1 = opt.target;
  if (t1.width > t1.fixedWidth) {
    t1.fontSize *= t1.fixedWidth / (t1.width + 1);
    t1.width = t1.fixedWidth;
  }
  if(t1.height > t1.fixedHeight){
  
    t1.fontSize *= t1.fixedHeight / (t1.height + 1);
    t1.height = t1.fixedHeight;
  }
  canvas.renderAll(); 
                 
});

canvas.add(t1);
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: in the code snippet, I don't see a border around the text.